# Cordova react app - links do not work in the iframe

Tags: reactjs, cordova, iframe, hyperlink, content-security-policy

I am not able to open links in the iframe in Cordova React app. The Xcode and Safari browser are giving me these kind of errors:

1. Refused to load https://github.com/google/roboto because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.
2. Refused to display 'https://github.com/google/roboto' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
3. WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
       filterBlacklist =     (
       );
       filterWhitelist =     (
       );
       restrictWeb = 1;
       useContentFilter = 0;
       useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
       whitelistEnabled = 0;
   }
4. WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
5. Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

I added the links into the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data:; img-src * data: blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; font-src 'self'; child-src 'self' https://github.com/google/roboto gap://ready; media-src 'none'; frame-ancestors https://github.com/google/roboto;">
```

and also used allow-intent and/or allow-navigation in the config.xml file.

But it still not working...

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me (using links in iframe):

```
<a href="https://github.com/google/roboto" onclick="parent.parent.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(this.href, '_system'); return false;">github.com/google/roboto</a>
```

Used plugin: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/